How to add default pickle type value in sqlalchemy in python
I have defined the pickle type column like below and create a table called test.
My intension is to add pickle data to the column and commit it.
Also if there is no value I want to add default pickle value (may be empty list or empty dict) to be added to the column.
If I try to execute below code
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Text, PickleType
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.mutable import Mutable, MutableList

Test1 = declarative_base()

class Test(Test1):

    __tablename__ = "test"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    test_name = Column(Text)
    test_list = Column(MutableList.as_mutable(PickleType))
    

    def __init__(self):

        self.test_name = " "
        self.test_list = []

Test.metadata.create_all(engine)


session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = session()
d1 = Test()

d1.test_name = 'test'
d1.test_list = []
session.add(d1)
session.commit()
session.close()

I get this error

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table test has no column named test_list
[SQL: INSERT INTO test (test_name, test_list) VALUES (?, ?)]
[parameters: ('test', <memory at 0x7fd610d21cc0>)]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)

Edited:
How to add dict type to the Pickle Column in the above example ?

Did you add the column to the model after the tables had been created?  If so you'll need to add the column to the table manually with ALTER TABLE or drop and recreate the table.  Note that the table name in the error doesn't match the table name in your code.

Thats right !!!
The table was already created. So I just had to delete the table and re-created it so it worked. Thaks

I have edited the question. Now I am interested to add dict type to Pickle column is it possible ?

The answer is drop the table and re-creted it again.
In my case the table was already created and I was trying to add new column and add data to it. So it was giving the error.
No change in the above code.

To define a default, pass a python function that returns the default value. SQLAlchemy will handle pickling and unpickling automatically, so you need only supply a Plain Old Python Object. See the docs here.
This example uses SQLAlchemy Core, but defaulting a value in the ORM works in exactly the same way.
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)

metadata = sa.MetaData()
tbl = sa.Table('t', metadata, sa.Column('c', sa.PickleType, default=list))

metadata.create_all(engine)

with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(tbl.insert())

with engine.connect() as conn:
    row = conn.execute(sa.select(tbl))
    print(list(row.mappings()))

The example code generates this output
2024-06-06 19:03:10,852 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine 
CREATE TABLE t (
        c BLOB
)


2024-06-06 19:03:10,852 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [no key 0.00006s] ()
2024-06-06 19:03:10,852 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
2024-06-06 19:03:10,852 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2024-06-06 19:03:10,853 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO t (c) VALUES (?)
2024-06-06 19:03:10,853 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00013s] (<memory at 0x72bcf1498880>,)
2024-06-06 19:03:10,853 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
2024-06-06 19:03:10,854 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2024-06-06 19:03:10,854 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT t.c 
FROM t
2024-06-06 19:03:10,854 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00013s] ()
[{'c': []}]

